# How to install PIL in Fedora 17 x86_64?

Tags: python, linux, gcc, fedora

I am installing PIL in my Fedora 17

But when I set up it, I got two Errors below:

```
/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libz.so when searching for -lz
/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.7.2/../../../libz.so when searching for -lz
/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /lib/libz.so when searching for -lz
/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libz.so when searching for -lz
/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/libpthread.so when searching for -lpthread
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have checked my gcc and python-devel, and they are both up to date.
Some said that it might be something to do with my x86_64 lib, so I tried to install lib32z-devel, but I couldn't yum install it.

Can any body help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please do a `locate libz.so`, if it can't locate do a `find / -name libz.so` and show us the output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install `zlib-devel` in order to be able to link against zlib.

Having said that, unless you have a particular reason for building PIL from source I would recommend just installing `python-imaging` with yum like this:

```
sudo yum install -y python-imaging
```

Comment: Wow! python-imaging is what I want! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Installing PIL via virtualenv requires building PIL's natively compiled components from source, thus it's something that is not all that infrequent.

Answer (score 0):

make sure python-devel and zlib-devel are installed then

install easy_install or pip
then
sudo easy_install Pillow
or
sudo pip install Pillow

Pillow is a fork of the python imaging library
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.3.0
http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

installing as above works on windows,linux (even on raspberrypi)